# Flash : Set link on Flash file

Tags: html, flash

I want to set link of another html page on flash file.

Comment: That question got answered just last week right here on stackoverflow. Did you try to use the search function?

Answer (score 0):

If you put one button or link on flash file, you may set the action of this button or link adding the code:

```
on(release) {
 getURL("www.youpage.com","_bank");
}
```